# How to convert a whole list of string to integer values in Scala

Tags: scala

So, I have a list of strings like this.

```
val x = List("12", "33", "77")
```

Is there a way to convert this whole List into integer values, like the following, without using a for loop?

```
result == List(12, 33, 77)
```

Comment: Vow, this syntax is awesome. Scala seems a pretty cool language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` the `List` using `toInt` :

```
List("12", "33", "77").map(_.toInt)
```

Or with a little more safety:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}
List("12", "33", "77", "bad").map(s => Try(s.toInt))
    .collect { case Success(x) => x }

res2: List[Int] = List(12, 33, 77)
```

Also:

```
List("12", "33", "77", "bad").filter(_.matches("[0-9]+")).map(_.toInt)
res7: List[Int] = List(12, 33, 77)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `flatMap` over `util.Try` like this,

```
x.flatMap( s => Try(s.toInt) toOption )
res: List[Int] = List(12, 33, 77)
```

Comment: That wiil silently discard bad entries